# Python: Hierarchical Slicing

Tags: python, numpy, slice, syntactic-sugar

Is there a more pythonic/numpythonic way to do some sort of nested/hierarchical slicing, i.e. a prettier version of this:

```
_sum = 0
for i in np.arange(n):
   _sum += someFunc(A[i,:])
```

Basically I would like to map `someFunc` (which takes arrays of any shape and returns a number) over the rows and then sum the results.

I have been thinking about `np.sum(someFunc(A[:,:]))`, but according to my understanding this will just map `someFunc`over the whole array.

Comment: `sum(np.apply_along_axis(someFunc,1,A))` though not a vectorized option?

Comment: What is `someFunc` supposed to be doing?

Comment: In this case, it is counting the number of equal values per row … But I have encountered this issue in quite a few instances, so I posed a slightly more general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could use a list comprehension like this:

```
sum([someFunc(A[i:]) for i in np.arange(n)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to count 1's in an array:

```
def foo(x):
    return (x==1).sum()
```

and a 2d array:

```
In [431]: X=np.array([[1,0,2],[3,1,1],[0,2,3]])
```

I can apply it iteratively to rows

```
In [432]: [foo(i) for i in X]   # iterate on 1st dimension
Out[432]: [1, 2, 0]
In [433]: [foo(X[i,:]) for i in range(3)]
Out[433]: [1, 2, 0]
```

and get the total count with `sum` (here the Python sum)

```
In [434]: sum([foo(X[i,:]) for i in range(3)])
Out[434]: 3
```

As written `foo` gets the same thing with applied to the whole array

```
In [435]: foo(X)
Out[435]: 3
```

and for row counts, use the `np.sum` axis control:

```
In [440]: np.sum(X==1, axis=1)
Out[440]: array([1, 2, 0])
```

`apply_along_axis` can to the same sort of row iteration:

```
In [438]: np.apply_along_axis(foo,1,X)
Out[438]: array([1, 2, 0])
```

but for this it is overkill.  It's more useful with 3d or larger arrays where it is awkward to iterate over all dimensions except the `nth` one.  It's never faster than doing your own iteration.

It's clearly best if you can write the function to work on the whole array.  But if you must iterate on rows, there aren't any magical solutions.  `vectorize` and `frompyfunc` wrap functions that work with scalar values, not 1d arrays.  Some `row` problems are solved by casting the rows as larger dtype objects (e.g. `unique` rows).